# How to correctly resize PKDrawing when layout changes?

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

I'm trying to layer a `PKCanvasView` on top of an image, which works fine with the initial layout but when the view is resized (by rotating the iPad) the `PKDrawing` within is not scaled which results in the image annotations being in the incorrect place. I'm struggling to work out how to correctly scale the `PKDrawing` to preserve the correct positions.

[image: An example showing the misplacement of my initial drawing]

This is an example demonstrating the issue:

```swift
class ImageDrawingView: UIView {

    private let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
    private let drawingView = PKCanvasView(frame: .zero)
    private let toolPicker = PKToolPicker()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        // Setup image view
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "TestImage") // Here I just used a screen grab of the lock screen
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        // Setup drawing view
        addSubview(drawingView)
        drawingView.isOpaque = false
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: drawingView)
        toolPicker.addObserver(drawingView)
        drawingView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        imageView.frame = bounds
        drawingView.frame = bounds
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let imageDrawingView = ImageDrawingView(frame: .zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(imageDrawingView)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        imageDrawingView.frame = view.bounds
    }
}
```

I think if I can calculate the transform, I can then use `drawingView.drawing.transform(using: transformScale)`. How do I go about calculating the transform please?